# Is it possible to embed a Power BI dashboard into an Medium article?

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

The medium.com [help page](https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/articles/214981378-Using-embeds) states that it supports Emdebly with over [300+ providers](https://embed.ly/providers). Would it be possible to embed a Power BI dashboard via one of these providers? Power BI is not listed, but perhaps it's possible by using one of the other providers? Or perhaps it's possible via a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

Power BI Embed is not among the supported embed services in Medium and they don't allow to run scripts.
So it is currently not possible to embed Power BI services in Medium.

**Reference:**

[Using embeds – Medium Help Center](https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/articles/214981378-Using-embeds)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Its possible to run various JS embeds. Therefore, I thought there might be a workaround.

Comment: Yes, they did include a list of supported embeds in the [link](https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/articles/214981378-Using-embeds), but PBI was not one of them.

Comment: I was thinking perhaps via javascript embedder and using the API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-customer-app), but that will probl. not work outside of orgs.

Comment: Even if you manage to run code snippets (Using GitHub gists, Codepen.io, etc.), I'll suggest you to use iframe (e.g.- in PBI web, File -> Embed Report -> Website or portal) otherwise you may expose your details